# What is the best approach for Authorization with node.js and Socket.io

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, socket.io

I have been "playing" with authentication using node.js, express and socket.io

I have tried the example here http://howtonode.org/socket-io-auth

```
app.use(express.cookieParser("rocks"));
app.use(express.session());

io.set('authorization', function(handshakeData, accept) {
    console.log('in authorization');
    if(handshakeData.headers.cookie) {
            handshakeData.cookie = cookie.parse(handshakeData.headers.cookie);
            handshakeData.sessionID = connect.utils.parseSignedCookie(handshakeData.cookie['express.sid']);
            if (handshakeData.cookie['express.sid'] == handshakeData.sessionID) {
                    return accept('Cookie is invalid.', false);
            }
    } else {
            return accept('No cookie transmitted.', false);
    }
    accept(null, true);
});
```

I keep getting an error generated by connect, more specifically this call line

```
  connect.utils.parseSignedCookie(handshakeData.cookie['express.sid']);

/workspace/node_modules/connect/node_modules/cookie-signature/index.js:39
if ('string' != typeof secret) throw new TypeError('secret required');
                                   ^
TypeError: secret required
```

I have tried to find the api documentation for express.cookieParser (which I have) and express.session (which I have not) and looked at the offending source code. I imagine there is something going on with the way I have set up the project as connect seems to have a cookieParser as well as express, or express is using the cookieParser from connect.

My package.json looks like

```
 {
  "name": "mplayer",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
 "dependencies": {
   "socket.io":"0.9.16",
    "express": "3.4.0",
   "jade": "*",
   "stylus": "*",
   "cookie": "*"
  }
}
```

Can someone please shed some light on why I am getting this error and secondly can **someone share the most effective way of authenticating a user using Node.js, socket.io and express** (I know there are various articles out there, but things seem to have moved on. It is hard to keep track of what is current).

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a secret for parsing signed cookies. This function:

```
connect.utils.parseSignedCookie();
```

Accepts two arguments, the first being `req.cookies`, the second being the secret. This is how you need to use the function:

```
var signedCookies = connect.utils.parseSignedCookie(handshake.headers.cookie, 'secret');
// signedCookies['express.sid']
```

The reason you're getting the error, is that you aren't passing a string as the second argument, which is what fails the `typeof 'string'` check.

As for the most effective way of authenticating Socket.IO users when used in conjunction with Express, it is already the way you're already using it.

Comment: Updated answer, it is actually a different reason.

Comment: If no cookie was transmitted should the client side set a cookie and re-try ?

Comment: If there is no cookie, there is no session. That also means you can't authenticate. The session is what reliably identifies each client from another.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var cookie = require('cookie');
var secret = config.get('session:secret');

io.set('authorization', function(handshake, callback){        
        async.waterfall([
            function(callback) {
                handshake.cookies = cookie.parse(handshake.headers.cookie || '');
                var sidCookie = handshake.cookies[config.get('session:key')];                
                var sid = cookieParser.signedCookie(sidCookie, secret);               
            }
        });
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser#cookieparser-signedcookie-str-secret-